# check onedrive access token status

Tags: php, jquery, onedrive

How to check if one drive access token is active or not? My code below is not working :( need help!

```
function check_one_drive_active(access_token){
    var od_api_root_url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/";
    var od_url_param = "?access_token="+access_token;
    var od_api_url = od_api_root_url+od_url_param;

    alert(od_api_url);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: od_api_url,
        dataType : "JSON",
        type : "POST",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.error.code);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is **Ajax cross domain not working in jquery**.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your xhr request?

Comment: my fault.. type : "POST" must be removed.. :) and is working now.. but still my problem is how to check if the access token is active or not? :(

Comment: **is how to check if the access token is active or not** Show what you have tried yet ?

Comment: @claire: Is it a 3rd party API ?

Comment: @claire and remove the image from answer section and put it in question section.

Comment: that's my screenshot below.. but what if the access_token is already expired.. how to check it?

Comment: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHWpv.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143146/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-claire).

Comment: any idea?.. :( how to check if access token is still active or how to make it expire?.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use the `/me/drive` endpoint, which is a common endpoint for retrieving information about the user's drive and also includes the access token in the request headers in ajax request.

```
function check_one_drive_active(access_token) {
    var od_api_root_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive";
    var od_api_url = od_api_root_url;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: od_api_url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("OneDrive access token is active");
            console.log(data); // You can log or process the response data here
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error checking OneDrive access token:", status, error);
            console.error(xhr.responseText);
            // Handle error or token expiration here
        }
    });
}

// Example usage:
// Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with the actual OneDrive access token
check_one_drive_active('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```